# e.preventDefault on child element in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<li ng-click="function()">
<div class="child">
<a href="#">something</a>
</div>
</li>
```

How to avoid `function()` been trigger when I click on `a` or `.child`? I know in jquery we do e.preventDefault(). But how about angularjs?

Comment: You do the exact same thing in Angular. Put an ng-click on the `div`, make it take `$event` (exact wording) as a parameter and call `preventDefault()`. Ie., `<div class='child' ng-click='$ctrl.onClick($event)'>` where `onClick = (event) => event.preventDefault()`

Comment: You don't do `e.preventDefault()` in `jQuery`, it's javascript. That's just a function you can call on any object of native event type. In angular it's exactly the same, since it's just "normal" javascript which gets executed on a `ngClick`. you just have to pass the event along with it (`ngClick="myFunc($event)"`) so it gets available in your declaration.